# SUPEE vs Upgrading to Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, upgrade, supee-6788

I have a list of pending SUPEE to patch, My magento is Magento ver. 1.7.0.2 and the pending SUPEEs that I need to patch are 7405, 8788, 9652,10266, 10415,10570 and 752. Is it better to upgrade to 1.9 or to patch all of this>? Will I avoid these patches if I will upgrade to 1.9? Thanks

Comment: Hi @Lyn welcome to Magento stackexchange. I think it is better to upgrade to latest version.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading is usually recommended, especially from 1.7. I manage several Magento sites still on Magento 1.7.0.2 and I have patched without any problems so patching is still a potential way to go. Upgrading to 1.9.3.10 would be my recommended course.

I do recommend using this tool for all patching: https://github.com/magesec/magesecuritypatcher.

Single most fantastic tool I have ever used. Bear in mind that it will replace any core changes, which is bad practice in the first place. Any local code changes will also not be changed so you may run into an issue if you have local code repos in use.